# Why Thunderbird cannot read root@localhost email?

Tags: thunderbird, root, postfix, dovecot

I'm using Postfix for sending emails, Dovecot as POP3 and Thunderbird. I can't login as root in Dovecot and Thunderbird doesn't show emails of root@localhost while it can show emails of other users. Is there any reason for Thunderbird not showing root's emails? I just need to know why Thunderbid and Dovecot doesn't allow accessing root stuffs. Thanks.
[image: thunderbird not showing root emails]

[image: cannot access root in dovecot]

Answer (score 0):

By default, dovecot only allows access to users with uid `500` and higher (https://wiki.dovecot.org/UserIds). You can modify this behaviour by changing the `first_valid_uid` variable in the configuration.

However, I have found resources (not authorative ones), that mentioned that UID 0 is hardcoded not to be accessible. You'd have to try but your mileage may vary.

Regardless of that, it would be a better idea to have root's email redirected to an admin's user account. You alleviate the risk of something going wrong with root's mail ánd you automatically get system notifications in your own mailbox.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, but may i know the reason why root emails access is forbidden?

Comment: @kekeke dovecot forks the child with euid/egid equal to the mailbox owner's ones and in case of root that is the serious possible security breach.

Comment: Thanks, what about the Thunderbird? It's running as user currently, and doesn't show root emails (/var/mail/root)

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot do not proceed the mail for `root@` and do not allows an access to the mailbox/maildir with UID/GID = 0 for security reasons. You have to create an alias for `root@host.tld` to the nonprivileged user. Dovecot has an options to set up the minimum acceptable values of UID/GID permitted:

```
first_valid_uid     = 1000
first_valid_gid     = 1000
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, what about the Thunderbird? It's running as user currently, and doesn't show root emails (/var/mail/root)

Comment: @kekeke This is an intended behaviour. TB initiate the dovecot serving process that should be launched with root's permissions to access the mailbox. This is potential security breach so dovecot do not allow an access to the root mailbox under any circumstances.

Comment: I can't find any article that help me with the Thunderbird question, i can read /var/mail/root through `sudo mail` and can see emails which were sent to root@localhost, while Thunderbird doesn't show them.

Comment: `sudo mail` reads the mailbox directly while TB uses the `dovecot` as an IMAP server. Therefore TB's behaviour is completely dependent on the `dovecot`'s security policy.

Comment: Ooooh, i didn't know that TB depends on dovecot, but before, i only had TB (didn't install `dovecot`, and it was still the same? So does TB really depend on `dovecot`? I don't think so, right?

Comment: You have to show your configs before any further analysis. MTA/POP/IMAP servers can be configured in a million different ways.

Comment: Before i installed `dovecot`, i only have postfix as STMP server, there was no IMAP/POP3 server